# Spring Boot project can't see data for database connection, written in application.yml

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, yaml

I'm writing a Java project in IntelliJ IDEA Community IDE. The technologies stack of this project:

- Spring Boot;
- Spring Data JPA;
- MySQL.

I have the `application.yml` file in project to connect with database, but when I run my app, I get an error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I'm at a loss why my project doesn't see my `application.yml` file, which locates in `/src/main/resources/database` path in project.

Any ideas?

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: mysql
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/map
    username: root
    password: abcd
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>example.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>geo-informer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Geo Informer</name>
    <description>
        The Spring Boot app, which makes interaction with the OpenStreetmap Nominatim API
        to work with geographic data and store it to the MySQL database
    </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This project is located here:

```
https://github.com/OlegSandro/geo-informer/tree/dev
```

Comment: it should be directly inside resources directory.

Comment: `application.yml` must be in `src/main/resources` not a sub-directory.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Thank you! It works! The question description is much more than its decision :)

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! You are right! You helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `application.yml` is not directly stored in `src/main/resources` it is not loaded.

In your `EntryPoint.java` file, you can add `@PropertySource` annotation and provide the path of your application.yml or you should store the file directly under the resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

The application.yml or application.properties file should be in your classpath when the project is build. 
Spring boot has designed its structure such that when a maven build is executed, the property files from src/main/resources are placed into the classes directory  with the other source files.

Therefore you need to directly place these files in src/main/resources

If you still wish to have the files elsewhere, you can point to the location with `@PropertySource`